# Excel 2007 - Using combination of Countif and Indirect

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have numeric data in column P in 50 different sheets ( each sheet has different person name). I have one summary Sheet which has names of all the worksheets in column A. In summary sheet column B against the name, i want to take count from each sheet. The criteria for count is to count all cells (in column P of individual sheets) which are having value > 0 or value < 0. IT should not count blank or zero values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a [countifs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)

`=COUNTIFS(P1:P10,"<>0",P1:P10,"<>"))`

Throw in some `indirect` like this:

`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$P$1:$P$10"),"<>",INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!$P$1:$P$10"),"<>0")`

and just drag it down.

Comment: Thanks...partly resolved. But i still i am not able to refer to the data in various sheets. I have all sheet names in column A of summary sheet..... how do i refer that ?

Comment: @user283476 updated for the indirect, sorry!